# Moroccan PhD student participating in science research in the UK for unpaid work. What type of visa do I need?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, internship

I am a PhD student living in Morocco. I found an internship research program in the  UK lasting 12 months. It is an unpaid position. I want to know which type of visa do I need?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The organisation offering the internship would have to sponsor your visa and they will be to help you with this. If they can't help it means they are not able to offer the position to non EU citizens.
There is some relevent information here https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-n-authorised-exchange-schemes